# Alternative to Apache Spark?

Tags: machine-learning, bigdata, apache-spark

I have been looking for a comprehensive alternative to Apache Spark for Big Data analytics/machine learning and couldn't find one. The ones which I have come across are:

- [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/)
- [Google DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/)
- [Apache Storm](http://storm.apache.org/)
- [SAS](https://www.sas.com/en_us/home.html)

Can any of these can be considered as a complete alternative/better than Spark? Or Spark is the only comprehensive Big Data analytics/machine learning engine there is these days?

Comment: Can you tell us why you need an alternative for Apache Spark?

Comment: The ray project https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ https://github.com/ray-project/ray

Comment: I look for alternative, because Spark is not superb performance-wise. I mean, when you created a "data preparation pipeline" - it may be OK for offline training, but you hardly can use the same pipeline for scoring. For the model speedup there is a separate product called "Mleap" - able to convert the model in something fast. But for the rest of the pipeline I see not performance hope.Strange...Also strange that best ML libs written in slower python, not in scala/java.

Comment: Have you looked into Google BigQuery?